# How to prevent Spring from trying to create indexes during MongoDB transactions?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-transactions

I am trying to utilize Spring Data Mongo with Transactions.  I initially ran into an issue where my inserts would fail due to Spring trying to create the collection and/or indexes during the first insert of a document.  I have since solved that issue by creating all of my collections and indexes on startup, prior to any transaction starting.  However, I am still using the Spring Data annotations to define the indexes (ie, `@Indexed`, `@CompoundIndexes`, etc.).  However, even though I have created all the indexes already, Spring is still trying to ensure/create the indexes during mongo processing.

In my situation, I am using inheritance with my data types.  Ie., `BasicUnit` which other Unit's extend.  If I go to store a particular type of Unit, and it is the first time I have tried to save that type of object during the current application run, Spring doesn't recognize it, and creates a new `PersistentEntity` for it.  As part of creating a new `PersistentEntity`, Spring posts an event, which `MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator` catches, which in turn tries to ensure all indexes are created, and thus an exception is thrown.

Here is the exception:

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 263 (OperationNotSupportedInTransaction): 'It is illegal to run command createIndexes in a multi-document transaction.' on server 127.0.0.1:27017. The full response is { "operationTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1560198052, "i" : 1 } }, "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "It is illegal to run command createIndexes in a multi-document transaction.", "code" : 263, "codeName" : "OperationNotSupportedInTransaction", "$clusterTime" : { "clusterTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1560198052, "i" : 1 } }, "signature" : { "hash" : { "$binary" : "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "$type" : "00" }, "keyId" : { "$numberLong" : "0" } } } }
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:179)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:293)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:255)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:444)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:72)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:200)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:269)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:131)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:123)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:242)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:233)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:170)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:163)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CreateIndexesOperation$1.call(CreateIndexesOperation.java:174)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CreateIndexesOperation$1.call(CreateIndexesOperation.java:169)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:453)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:415)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CreateIndexesOperation.execute(CreateIndexesOperation.java:169)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CreateIndexesOperation.execute(CreateIndexesOperation.java:70)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:193)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeCreateIndexes(MongoCollectionImpl.java:805)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.createIndexes(MongoCollectionImpl.java:800)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.createIndexes(MongoCollectionImpl.java:793)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.createIndex(MongoCollectionImpl.java:778)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:246)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.SessionAwareMethodInterceptor.invoke(SessionAwareMethodInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy202.createIndex(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.DefaultIndexOperations.lambda$ensureIndex$0(DefaultIndexOperations.java:135)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:545)
```

Here is the call stack leanding up to the call to ensureIndex:

```
DefaultIndexOperations.lambda$ensureIndex$0(IndexDefinition, MongoCollection) line: 135 
1894975953.doInCollection(MongoCollection) line: not available  
MongoTemplate.execute(String, CollectionCallback<T>) line: 545  
DefaultIndexOperations.execute(CollectionCallback<T>) line: 218 
DefaultIndexOperations.ensureIndex(IndexDefinition) line: 121   
MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.createIndex(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$IndexDefinitionHolder) line: 145   
MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.checkForAndCreateIndexes(MongoPersistentEntity<?>) line: 135  
MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.checkForIndexes(MongoPersistentEntity<?>) line: 127   
MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.onApplicationEvent(MappingContextEvent<?,?>) line: 111    
MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent) line: 54 
SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(ApplicationListener, ApplicationEvent) line: 172 
SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(ApplicationListener<?>, ApplicationEvent) line: 165    
SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(ApplicationEvent, ResolvableType) line: 139    
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).publishEvent(Object, ResolvableType) line: 398    
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).publishEvent(ApplicationEvent) line: 355  
MongoMappingContext(AbstractMappingContext<E,P>).addPersistentEntity(TypeInformation<?>) line: 405  
MongoMappingContext(AbstractMappingContext<E,P>).getPersistentEntity(TypeInformation<?>) line: 248  
MongoMappingContext(AbstractMappingContext<E,P>).getPersistentEntity(Class<?>) line: 191    
MongoMappingContext(AbstractMappingContext<E,P>).getPersistentEntity(Class) line: 85    
MongoMappingContext(MappingContext<E,P>).getRequiredPersistentEntity(Class<?>) line: 73 
EntityOperations$AdaptibleMappedEntity<T>.of(T, MappingContext<MongoPersistentEntity<?>,MongoPersistentProperty>, ConversionService) line: 600  
EntityOperations$AdaptibleMappedEntity<T>.access$100(Object, MappingContext, ConversionService) line: 580   
EntityOperations.forEntity(T, ConversionService) line: 105  
MongoTemplate.doInsert(String, T, MongoWriter<T>) line: 1237
```

You can see where Spring tries to *get* the persistent entity, then finally decides to *add*, and then fires off the event, and then the event is handled by attempting to create indexes.

I need to know how to prevent Spring from attempting to create those indexes during a transaction.

The things I have considered

1. Try to figure out how to pre-register all my persistent entities,
   but I'm not sure how to do that besides manually keeping a list, or
   writing code to scan the classpath to find all classes that are
   annotated by @Document or extend such a class.
2. Completely abandon Spring's index annotations and only use explicit calls to
   ensureIndex for every index I need.

Neither of these solutions is very attractive to me.

I find it hard to believe that no one else has run into similar index issues using Spring Data Mongo with Transactions, so any of you know a solution to this problem, I would love to hear it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it was caused by my java package arrangement.  It appears that Spring MongoDB will scan and register all `@Document` and `@Persistent` entities in the same package as the `MongoConfiguration` by default.  However, I happen to have that class in a different package than all of my entities.

I overrode the `MongoConfigurationSupport#getMappingBasePackages` in my `MongoConfiguration` and then Spring was able to find and 'pre-register' all of my entities, so they are no longer 'discovered' in the middle of a transaction.

```
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

....

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.MongoConfigurationSupport#getMappingBasePackages()
     */
    @Override
    protected Collection<String> getMappingBasePackages() {
        java.util.List<String> packages = new ArrayList<>(1);
        packages.add("my.entity.base.package");
        return packages;
    }
}
```

Comment: as of Spring Data MongoDB 2.2 it will be possible to configure index creation by overriding `boolean autoIndexCreation()`

Answer (score 9):

```
Automatic index creation will be disabled by default as of Spring Data MongoDB 3.x.     Please use 'MongoMappingContext#setAutoIndexCreation(boolean)' or override 'MongoConfigurationSupport#autoIndexCreation()' to be explicit.  However, we recommend setting up indices manually in an application ready block. You may use index derivation there as well.

> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
> public void initIndicesAfterStartup() {
>
>     IndexOperations indexOps = mongoTemplate.indexOps(DomainType.class);
>
>     IndexResolver resolver = new MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver(mongoMappingContext);
>     resolver.resolveIndexFor(DomainType.class).forEach(indexOps::ensureIndex);
> }
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> Try this

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void initIndicesAfterStartup() {    
  log.info("Mongo InitIndicesAfterStartup init");
  var init = System.currentTimeMillis();

  var mappingContext = this.mongoConverter.getMappingContext();

  if (mappingContext instanceof MongoMappingContext) {
    var mongoMappingContext = (MongoMappingContext) mappingContext;

    for (BasicMongoPersistentEntity<?> persistentEntity : mongoMappingContext.getPersistentEntities()) {
      var clazz = persistentEntity.getType();
      if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Document.class)) {
        var indexOps = mongoTemplate.indexOps(clazz);
        var resolver = new MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver(mongoMappingContext);                    
        resolver.resolveIndexFor(clazz).forEach(indexOps::ensureIndex);
      }
    }
  }
  log.info("Mongo InitIndicesAfterStartup take: {}", (System.currentTimeMillis() - init));
}
```

remember that var is only for java 11+

Comment: Could you please guide on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60003179/please-use-mongomappingcontextsetautoindexcreationboolean-or-override-mong