# Please use 'MongoMappingContext#setAutoIndexCreation(boolean)' or override 'MongoConfigurationSupport#autoIndexCreation()' to be explicit

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I went through https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.2.0.RC1/reference/html/#mapping-usage and other sources on the web, but the solution did not work for me.

I am using Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE and Spring Data Mongo. In this example, at Model/Pojo field level we're using

```
@Indexed(name = AppConstants.FIRSTNAME_INDEX, direction = IndexDirection.ASCENDING)
private String firstName;
```

Error:

```
Please use 'MongoMappingContext#setAutoIndexCreation(boolean)' or override 'MongoConfigurationSupport#autoIndexCreation()' to be explicit.
However, we recommend setting up indices manually in an application ready block. You may use index derivation there as well.

> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
> public void initIndicesAfterStartup() {
>
>     IndexOperations indexOps = mongoTemplate.indexOps(DomainType.class);
>
>     IndexResolver resolver = new MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver(mongoMappingContext);
>     resolver.resolveIndexFor(DomainType.class).forEach(indexOps::ensureIndex);
> }
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As suggested in the log, I implemented, but I don't see method setAutoIndexCreation.

```
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Disable auto index creation in application.properties file

```
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=false
```

or application.yml file

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      auto-index-creation: false
```

Create the class MongoConfiguration whit @Configuration annotation

Injetc this dependencies

```
private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
private final MongoConverter mongoConverter;
```

and add this method

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void initIndicesAfterStartup() {

    log.info("Mongo InitIndicesAfterStartup init");
    var init = System.currentTimeMillis();

    var mappingContext = this.mongoConverter.getMappingContext();

    if (mappingContext instanceof MongoMappingContext) {
        MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext = (MongoMappingContext) mappingContext;
        for (BasicMongoPersistentEntity<?> persistentEntity : mongoMappingContext.getPersistentEntities()) {
            var clazz = persistentEntity.getType();
            if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Document.class)) {
                var resolver = new MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver(mongoMappingContext);

                var indexOps = mongoTemplate.indexOps(clazz);
                resolver.resolveIndexFor(clazz).forEach(indexOps::ensureIndex);
            }
        }
    }

    log.info("Mongo InitIndicesAfterStartup take: {}", (System.currentTimeMillis() - init));
}
```

remember that var is only for java 11+

The final class, which uses Lombok

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoConverter;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext;


@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration {

private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

private final MongoConverter mongoConverter;

@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void initIndicesAfterStartup() {

        log.info("Mongo InitIndicesAfterStartup init");
        var init = System.currentTimeMillis();

        var mappingContext = this.mongoConverter.getMappingContext();

        if (mappingContext instanceof MongoMappingContext) {
            MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext = (MongoMappingContext) mappingContext;
            for (BasicMongoPersistentEntity<?> persistentEntity : mongoMappingContext.getPersistentEntities()) {
                var clazz = persistentEntity.getType();
                if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Document.class)) {
                    var resolver = new MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver(mongoMappingContext);

                    var indexOps = mongoTemplate.indexOps(clazz);
                    resolver.resolveIndexFor(clazz).forEach(indexOps::ensureIndex);
                }
            }
        }

        log.info("Mongo InitIndicesAfterStartup take: {}", (System.currentTimeMillis() - init));
    }

}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't works when you've replica set

Comment: Where did you find the property `auto-index-creation`? I used the property, but it is still creating indices on startupt. I can't find it in the doc either used in the code. In [MongoConfigurationSupport.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/2.2.x/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/config/MongoConfigurationSupport.java) `autoIndexCreation` is hard coded to true. I do not find a property usage.

Comment: Harshana Samaranayake For me too

Answer (score 1):

But the solution doesn't work well, at least within the reactive context. The `mongoMappingContext.getPersistentEntities()` is empty at this time. Only `auto-index-creation: true` (or even `mongoMappingContext.setAutoIndexCreation(true)`) ensure the creation of indexes.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Juan Ibarra comment, adding this to application.yml file didnt work for me:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      auto-index-creation: false
```

but overriding autoIndexCreation() in AbstractMongoClientConfiguration worked:

```
@Override
protected boolean autoIndexCreation() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I was having issues with this on Spring-Boot 3.1.8 / Spring-Data-Mongodb 4.1.8. Whether using `spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation` or `spring.data.mongodb.autoIndexCreation` as I saw someone suggest - neither works, but when overriding in the AbstractMongoClientConfiguration class, it does work. Notably, this was only happening while we were customizing MongoTemplate.java with our own bean. When I adjusted that bean to initially create the template via the `MongoTemplate(MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDbFactory, @Nullable MongoConverter mongoConverter)` signature, that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

tried with the following configuration, I even created an own mappingContext bean

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    private final AbstractCloudConfig abstractCloudConfig;

    @Autowired
    public MongoConfiguration(AbstractCloudConfig abstractCloudConfig) {
        this.abstractCloudConfig = abstractCloudConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder().build());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() {
        return abstractCloudConfig.connectionFactory().mongoDbFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingMongoConverter mongoConverter(MappingMongoConverter mongoConverter) {
        /*
         * For some obscure reason, Spring Mongo does not like hash maps with keys that contain dots '.'.
         * We configure to replace dots '.' in maps with some obscure character that does not occur in in keys.
         */
        mongoConverter.setMapKeyDotReplacement("~");
        return mongoConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        MongoMappingContext mappingContext = new MongoMappingContext();
        mappingContext.setInitialEntitySet(this.getInitialEntitySet());
        mappingContext.setSimpleTypeHolder(this.customConversions().getSimpleTypeHolder());
        mappingContext.setFieldNamingStrategy(this.fieldNamingStrategy());
        mappingContext.setAutoIndexCreation(false);
        return mappingContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        throw new RuntimeException("This method should not be called");
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void initIndicesAfterStartup() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
        this.mongoMappingContext().setAutoIndexCreation(false);
        createIndexForEntity(DataSetDefinitionV2.class, mongoTemplate);
        createIndexForEntity(ModelConfiguration.class, mongoTemplate);
        createIndexForEntity(ScheduleEntity.class, mongoTemplate);
    }

    private void createIndexForEntity(Class<?> entityClass, MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        IndexOperations indexOps = mongoTemplate.indexOps(entityClass);
        IndexResolver resolver = new MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver(this.mongoMappingContext());
        resolver.resolveIndexFor(entityClass).forEach(indexOps::ensureIndex);
    }
}
```

still the warning comes.I event tried spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=false in application.properties, also no luck