# @Document doesn't create a collection in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-mongodb

I have a simple spring boot rest application. Trying to create a collection using @Document annotation in spring data mongo db. I know spring framework creates a collection if the document is denoted with @Document annotation.

## Entity

```
@Document("User")
public class User {
    @Id
    private String Id;
    @Field("firstName")
    @TextIndexed
    private String firstName;
    @Field("lastName")
    @TextIndexed
    private String lastName;
    private String address;

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

## properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/Order
```

However, in the rest controller, it creates a collection on insert command, but still, it doesn't create a Text-index on insert.

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public Controller(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public String Get(){
        mongoTemplate.insert(new User());
        return "HelloWorld";
    }
}
```

Don't have any error in the console as well

## Console

```
2020-09-03 12:52:00.657  INFO 865 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on macbooks-MacBook-Air.local with PID 865 (/Users/macbook/Projects/Fete/demo/build/classes/java/main started by macbook in /Users/macbook/Projects/Fete/demo)
2020-09-03 12:52:00.662  INFO 865 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-09-03 12:52:02.676  INFO 865 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-09-03 12:52:02.712  INFO 865 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 22ms. Found 0 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2020-09-03 12:52:04.106  INFO 865 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-09-03 12:52:04.136  INFO 865 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-09-03 12:52:04.137  INFO 865 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
2020-09-03 12:52:04.269  INFO 865 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-09-03 12:52:04.270  INFO 865 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3500 ms
2020-09-03 12:52:04.558  INFO 865 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
2020-09-03 12:52:04.692  INFO 865 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:9}] to localhost:27017
2020-09-03 12:52:04.731  INFO 865 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=8, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=8577619}
2020-09-03 12:52:06.165  INFO 865 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-09-03 12:52:06.746  INFO 865 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-09-03 12:52:06.764  INFO 865 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 6.69 seconds (JVM running for 13.238)
```

Code repository

```
https://github.com/anandjaisy/mongoDBSpringBoot
```

Comment: you get any error?

Comment: No, I don't get any errors

Comment: How did you call `mongoTemplate.insert(new User()); `

Comment: I called from the rest API controller, it insert an empty record , however doesn't creates text index

Comment: can you show us

Comment: Here is the repo - https://github.com/anandjaisy/mongoDBSpringBoot

Comment: gone through your code, firstly, as it is insert, you implement a PostMapping, not GetMapping. With PostMapping you can send a User object in request body from postman plugin. You are getting empty record, because you are not setting any data in code or not even sending a request object User through @RequestParam. Pls go through some tutorial

Comment: @dinesh it's not about rest API call, my question is about document annotation. That rest API is just a sample, you can skip that part, when I run the application , a collection should get created. It's not about what I did in the rest API.

Comment: Mongo creates a document as your trying to insert, if that document does not exist prior, it creates one. Simple. But without trying to insert, by just having a class with @Document, nothing happens

Comment: I have a other sample application which is doing exactly what I am saying, you need to do some research on spring data mongo. Spring data does creates a collection with @Document annotation. Even that mongo.template.insert is not creating text index on my sample application

Comment: @DineshDontha check out this repository- https://github.com/anandjaisy/sampleMongoApplication this creates a collection with the Document annotation

Comment: It has only @Document & a spring boot main class, it might create the collection in mongodb, but it will not create any records(documents). If you still doubt, then delete the collection in monhodb & re-run it. Thanks, Goodluck

Comment: Yes, that's correct it won't create any records. It will only create a collection, at least it is creating a TextIndex but for my sample code It doesn't do that as well. What's wrong with my code

Answer (score 0):

I have to set implicitly to work

In application.properties file

```
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true
```

Or application.yml file

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      auto-index-creation: true
```

Reference - [Please use 'MongoMappingContext#setAutoIndexCreation(boolean)' or override 'MongoConfigurationSupport#autoIndexCreation()' to be explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60003179/please-use-mongomappingcontextsetautoindexcreationboolean-or-override-mong)